# Validating a field in Create Profile Form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a Create Profile Form after registration and my codes are below.Its already working only for a slight problem,that is,if the `name` field of `Profile` model matches one in database,django brings an error message `column slug is not unique` .I see that slug field is clashing with another,how am I going to edit the below codes to raise a validation error message if name submitted is similiar to one in  db?

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description=models.TextField()
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def create_profile(request):
    form_class = ProfileForm

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            profile = form.save(commit=False)

            profile.user = request.user
            profile.slug = slugify(profile.name)

            profile.save()

            slug = slugify(profile.name)
            return redirect('profile_details', slug=profile.slug)

    else:
        form = form_class()
        return render(request, 'profile/create_profile.html', {'form': form,})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[url(r'^accounts/create_profile/$',views.create_profile,name='registration_create_profile'),]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelForm`s actually [validate uniqueness](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) as part of the `is_valid()` checks.

The problem in your case is that you are manually setting the `slug` after running `is_valid()`. Because of this you will have to manually validate uniqueness after setting the slug. Something like this would work:

```
if form.is_valid():
    profile = form.save(commit=False)

    profile.user = request.user
    profile.slug = slug = slugify(profile.name)

    # Check slug uniqueness, keep appending a digit until it fits
    n = 1
    while Profile.objects.filter(slug=profile.slug).exists():
        # Need to find a new slug.
        profile.slug = '%s-%d' % (slug, n)
        n += 1

    profile.save()

    return redirect('profile_details', slug=profile.slug)
```

Note that it is probably better to perform this uniqueness check inside the model's `save()` method instead of in the view - this just illustrates the logic.

Alternatively you could use a library like [django-autoslug](https://github.com/neithere/django-autoslug/) which performs this logic for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight it worked perfect. But what if I want to ensure that names are unique, so it raises an Validation error message that 'Name already exists '.Since the doc says that is_valid() ensures a field label with unique =true is field, I tried putting an already used name while making it unique in model, but it brings up '...View returns none'

Comment: If you want names to be unique then you should specify `unique=True` in the model field definition.